# How to simulate the downloading of a file during java unit testing?

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I can't figure out how to simulate downloading from a file path in spring with Map<Long, String>
I've implemented this method:

```
    @Test
    void testDownloadFile() throws Exception {
        Long fileId = 1L;

        file.put(0L, "value");
        File fileTemp = new File("file");
        rse.setFilePath(file);
        when(myService.getFileByKey(fileId, 0L)).thenReturn(fileTemp);

        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(rseController).build();

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/rse/document/download/" + file.get(0L))).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(response.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)).isEqualTo(
                "attachment; filename=\"" + fileTemp.getName() + "\"");
        assertThat(response.getContentType()).isEqualTo(MediaType.parseMediaType(FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileTemp.getName()).toString()));
    }
```

But I have a error 400 :
`org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:  Expecting: [400] to be equal to: [200] but was not. at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller`
Help-me please.

I've tried to redo it, but I've got the 400 error explained above, but I'm waiting for the 200 error to say ok, I'd like at least one clue to solve my problem.

Comment: Status code 400 is 'Bad Request', so your client request (in your test class) is malformed. You should show your Controller method which should receive and handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem, error 400 - 500 and so on, check the call for services in the controller.

```
        @Test
    void testDownloadFile() throws Exception {
        // download
        Long fileId = 1L;

        // Simuler l'appel de la méthode getDocumentById() sur documentService
        Document file = new Document();
        file.setFileType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
        file.setFileName("hello.txt");
        file.setData("Hello, World!".getBytes());
        when(documentService.getDocumentById(fileId)).thenReturn(file);

        // Créer un objet MockMvc pour exécuter la requête
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(rseController).build();

        // Exécuter une requête GET pour télécharger le fichier
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/rse/document/download/" + fileId)).andReturn();

        // Vérifier que la réponse est celle attendue
        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(response.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)).isEqualTo(
                "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFileName() + "\"");
        assertThat(response.getContentType()).isEqualTo(MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getFileType()).toString());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsByteArray()).isEqualTo(file.getData());
    }
```

So don't lose heart

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).